# Element disapears in the Safari browser after hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, overflow

My footer contains a list of 4 items.
If I hover and scroll down to the 4th item, then move the cursor out, I need to go back to the initial position.

In order to achieve this, I had to play with my overflow tag.
When I hover the footer my overflow is set to initial, when I hover-out it is set to scroll.

Everything works fine on Chrome but not on Safari.

**How can I keep my div in the initial top position when I've hovered out without making my content disappearing?**

```css
/* FOOTER */

p.black {
  font-family: helvetica;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  color: black;
}

p#footer {
  display: block;
  font-size: 44px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: "helvetica";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  //padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  //border-bottom: 1px solid #868686;
}

.info--footer {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  padding: 25px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}

.footer {
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999999999999999999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4rem;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 15rem 15rem 0rem 0rem;
  background: black;
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .footer {
    border-radius: 12.5rem 12.5rem 0rem 0rem;
    background: hsla(0, 0%, 52%, 0.5);
    //background: hsla(0, 0%, 32%, 0.8);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2rem);
    //height:160px;
    height: 140px;
    overflow: initial;
  }
}

.footer:hover {
  height: 380px;
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .footer:hover {
    overflow: scroll;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
    height: 80vh;
  }
}

.footer:hover>.card--container {
  background: blue;
}

.footer-show {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  bottom: 0;
}

.footer-hide {
  //transition:  0.2s ease-in;
  bottom: -.1rem;
}

.card--container {
  cursor: pointer!important;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 3rem;
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .card--container {
    //background: red;
    display: grid;
    padding: 0rem;
    //margin-top: 100px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .card--container:hover {
    background: black;
    display: grid;
    padding: 0rem;
    //margin-top: 100px;
  }
}

a.menu_item {
  cursor: pointer!important;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  a.menu_item {
    //background:red;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer!important;
    //padding: 1rem 0;
    display: block;
    padding: 2rem 0;
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/*OTHER IMG*/

img.small-card-lost-tapes {
  background: #3c3c3b;
}

img.small-card-sounds {
  background: #6e32ff;
}

img.small-card-orgy {
  background-color: #CABA9F!important;
}

img.small-card-tribe {
  background-color: #fe0000;
}

#small-card-footer {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transform: scale(1);
}

#small-card-footer:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  #small-card-footer:hover {
    transform: none;
  }
}

img#small-card-footer {
  padding: 3rem;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  img#small-card-footer {
    border-radius: 1.5rem;
    //width: 220px;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    padding: 1.8rem;
  }
}


/*FOOTER */
```

```html
<p class="black">HOVER BELOW ⬇️ ⬇️ ⬇️ ON SAFARI (CHROME WORK FINE)</p>
<footer class="hide-me footer footer-hide text-center">
  <p id="footer">WHY IM DISAPPEARING AFTER OVER? </p>
  <p class="info--footer mobile--show">
    The content inside the blue container need to be scrollable!
    <br>after hover I have to go back to the initial position</p>
  <div class="card--container">
    <a href="/orgy.html" class="hide-img menu_item">
      <img class="small-card-orgy" id="small-card-footer" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Numbers.svg/1079px-Numbers.svg.png" data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Numbers.svg/1079px-Numbers.svg.png"></a>
    <a href="/sounds.html" class="hide-img menu_item">
      <img class="small-card-sounds" id="small-card-footer" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Numbers.svg/1079px-Numbers.svg.png" data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Numbers.svg/1079px-Numbers.svg.png"></a>
    <a href="/tapes.html" class="hide-img menu_item">
      <img class="small-card-lost-tapes" id="small-card-footer" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Numbers.svg/1079px-Numbers.svg.png" data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Numbers.svg/1079px-Numbers.svg.png"></a>
    <a href="/tribe.html" class="hide-img menu_item">
      <img class="small-card-tribe" id="small-card-footer" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Numbers.svg/1079px-Numbers.svg.png" data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Numbers.svg/1079px-Numbers.svg.png"></a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**SOLUTION? ...**

(Also firing JS would be fine)

Comment: It works fine for me on safari 13, I see it the same way